# Illuminate/Queue/Events/JobFailed.php: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-envoyer

I'm running deployments with Laravel Envoyer.

After activating the release, I have this deployment hook running against all servers:

```
cd {{ release }}

npm install
npm run build
npm run nova-prod
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan optimize:clear
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Lately, for reasons I haven't been able to figure out, I am getting a lot of these types of errors when I run jobs:

> include(/home/forge/example.com/releases/20240211054906/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Events/JobFailed.php):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> include(/home/forge/example.com/releases/20240211054906/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.php):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I've tried manually restarting all queue workers, but still getting this issue.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Looks like there were some long running queue workers from a deleted release directory that were stuck in memory that didn't get the restart signal. The only solution to this was to either find them manually on the server and kill them...or just wait patiently for them to die on their own.